# Alter Statement Filling Transaction Log File Fast and not completing

Tags: sql-server

I have ran below alter statement which was part of deployment but while running this tr-log file getting full quickly.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MY_ORDER_LINE] ALTER COLUMN [CREATED_BY]  INT NULL ;   --This has not yet been updated – column data type is still ‘smallint’

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MY_ORDER_LINE] ALTER COLUMN [LAST_UPDATED_BY] INT NULL;  --  This has not yet been updated – column data type is still ‘smallint’

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MY_ORDER_LINE] ALTER COLUMN [LAST_UPDATE_LOGIN] INT NULL;  --  This has not yet been updated – column data type is still ‘smallint’

GO
```

SQL Server Version:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3000.0 (X64) 
Oct 19 2012 13:38:57 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)
```

OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 standard 64 bit

RAM: 8 GB

Log file size: 53 gb

I have arranged the space but now this query is running from past 120 mins and not completing.

There is no blocking also.

What to do to get it complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try each individual `ALTER` statement by itself, see if that helps.

Unfortunately, beyond that, you can't do an `ALTER` in batches of, say, 1000 records like you can with an `UPDATE` or `DELETE`.

You *can* do the following, though:

1. Create a new table `[My_Order_Line_New]` with the proper column definitions
2. Do an `INSERT` to copy all rows from the old table into the new. This you can do in batches, so your log doesn't explode.
3. Rename the tables: change `[My_Order_Line]` to `[My_Order_Line_Old]`, then `[My_Order_Line_New]` to `[My_Order_Line]`.

Answer (score -2):

Switch to Simple Recovery, run the ALTER statement, then switch back to Transactional Recovery.

Comment: This answer works in many cases, but not for an `ALTER TABLE`. Even in simple mode, the entire transaction must complete at once or be rolled back.

Comment: I have tried this currently these alter statement running on SIMPLE RECOVERY